# Validation Rule to Prevent Editing Records by Some Profiles When Record is in Certain Status

Tags: validation-rule

**Use Case:**

IF the Account Status (status is a a picklist)  is  "Pending Review"  or "Active" Then Only  Profile "CSX" and "" System Admin" can edit the record

I have Created this Validation rule

```
AND (

          OR($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", $Profile.Name <> "CSX"),

          OR (ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Active") , ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Pending Review")),
          
          NOT (ISNEW()),

          RecordType.DeveloperName = "Licensee"

         )
```

The validation rule does not work as expected. When the CSX user logs in and edits the record, the user gets the 'WE hit a snag'  error.
Similarly all other users including System Admin get the 'we hit the snag'  error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that validation rules are better called *invalidation* rules. They tell you when data is bad, not when it's good. Don't try to construct this like you would construct an `if()` condition in Apex.

At first glance, the `OR($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", $Profile.Name <> "CSX")` should be making your spidey-senses tingle.
A user can only have a single profile, so at least one of those comparisons will always return true. If one is always true, then the entire `OR()` is always true.

That `OR()` for your profile check should be an `AND()` instead. If a user is both not a sysadmin and not CSX, then there is a chance you want your rule to fire. Being a member of either one of those two profiles is sufficient to exclude that user from your rule.

```
AND (
    AND($Profile.Name <> "System Administrator", $Profile.Name <> "CSX"),
    OR (ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Active") , ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Pending Review")),
    NOT (ISNEW()),
    RecordType.DeveloperName = "Licensee"
)
```

You could simplify a little by pulling the profile checks out of the nested `AND()` (because the outermost operation is an `AND()`), but there's little harm in keeping that as is, and separating that section into its own "group" can help others read the validation rule.

Alternatively, you could create and assign a Custom Permission to manage this instead of relying on profiles.